# How to conclude whether a given function is convex or non-convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In my work, I came across the following equation:

$\text{P}3: \underset{x,p}{\text{max}}\sum_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sum_{j\in \mathcal{J}}\sum_{s\in \mathcal{S}}w_i x_{ij}^s \text{log}_2 \Biggl(\frac{\log_2(1+\gamma_{ij}^s)}{\sum_{l\in \mathcal{I}}w_lx_{lj}^s}\Biggr)$---(1)

subject to
$C_1 :$ $\sum_{j\in \mathcal{J}} \sum_{s\in S}x_{ij}^s = 1, \forall i \in \mathcal{I},\\C_2: 0\leq p_j^s \leq P_j^s, \forall j \in \mathcal{J}, \forall s \in \mathcal{S}\\ C_3: \sum_{s\in \mathcal{S}} p_j^s \leq P_j, \forall j \in \mathcal{J},\\C_4: x_{i,j}^s \in \{0,1\}, \forall i \in \mathcal{I}, \forall j \in \mathcal{J}, \forall s \in \mathcal{S}$

where $\mathcal{I} = \{1,\dots,i,\dots,I\}$ is set of users, $\mathcal{J} = \{1,\dots,j,\dots,J\}$ is set of cellphone towers and $\mathcal{S} = \{1,\dots,s,\dots,S\}$, $x_{ij} = \{0,1\}$ is set of frequencies associated with each tower and $w$ denotes the weight used for associating user to tower.

My query is how equation (1) is nonconvex with respect to $x$ and $p$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify the expression at all?

Comment: Thank u sir for your response. Yes...its a complicated expression but how we say that its a nonconvex expression. My doubt arises because in next step the authors of the paper (from where this equation is taken) they made slight relaxation and claims that now the expression becomes convex in nature....Sir shall I show you that expression here ?